# association between User and Person in OOP model

Tags: php, database, oop

I'm thinking about User and Person relationship in OOP and DB model.
Person is someone who use the application, for example a buyer for web-shop application.
To use the application, person has to be application User which can login and logout.
Let's say I have this:

```
Person (id, firstname, givenname, address, phone)
User (id, e-mail, username, password)
```

How to connect this two entities with association ?

Should User have person_id: `User (id, e-mail, username, password, PERSON_ID)`

Or should Person have user_id: `Person (id, firstname, givenname, address, phone, USER_ID)`

Please, tell me if I went completely wrong direction.

(I'll use PHP and laravel but that's not so important for this question).

Comment: Do you know that there are ways to get inheritance also in relational databases? Like in `Person extends User { }`. It might be interesting for you to study it.

Comment: I know but I'm not sure that inheritance is the way to go here.. Can you please give me some arguments why to use inheritance ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of your data.

Do you need to have users and persons being seperate entities? If you have some users who are not persons (eg. system user, cron user, etc.) then have Person contain a user ID. If that's not a concern for you (ie. all Users are Persons, period), I would create a single table containing all of the data, it's simpler.

I can't think of a case where I would want a User containing a Person ID.